# useState to receive input data and post to console

Tags: reactjs, input, use-state

Still a junior with React and I'm trying to detect an input from the front end and use useState to collect the input data and post it through the console. I followed React's own tutorial but I can't get this right. It's probably something small I'm forgetting but I've been stuck on this for days. Please help.

```
function Cards2() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState();
  console.log(input);

  return (
    <div id="cards" style={{width: 'auto', margin: '10px'}}>
    <div className="card-header" id="card-header" style={{backgroundColor: 'dimgray', color: 'white'}}>
      <h5>Header</h5>
    </div>
    <div className="card-body" id="card-body" style={{backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'}}>
      <blockquote className="blockquote mb-0">
        <p>Enter Name:</p>

                <input onChange={() => setInput(input)} type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"/> 

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" style={{marginTop: '7px'}}> Submit </button>

        <footer className="blockquote-footer">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
export default Cards2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onChange handler in Input needs to be like this:

```
<input onChange={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)} type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"/>
```

You can use `useEffect` as suggested in previous answer but that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `useEffect` to track any changes to the input value (or any state value, for that matter). The following link also explains how useEffect works, and how to work it with input.
https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-hook-examples/

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Cards2() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(input);
  }, [input]);

  return (
    // your code here
  );
}

export default Cards2;
```

Comment: Technically you don't need `useEffect` here. While it will ensure logging once per change to the value, calling `setInput` will cause the component will rerender.